# SQLite .output stdout

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to export a csv file to a fixed length file.
I'm using SQLite because I have to process the file.

The problem I'm having is with the output.

Here is the code I am running from a sql file:

```
.output stdout          --send output to screen
.echo off
.headers off 
.separator ','
.mode column

.open tmp.db
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS myData;

.import 'C:\2015.csv' myData
.width 4 4 1 6 16 2 6 

.output myData.txt      --send output to file
select * from myData;

.output stdout          --send output back to screen
.print "File was created."

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS myData;
vacuum;
.print "tmp.db vacuum complete"
.print "Type '.exit' or '.quit' to exit SQLite"

.exit
```

The problem is that in the first line, where I send the output to the screen, I get an error:

> Error: unknown command or invalid arguments: "output". Enter ".help"
>   for help

The script executes, but it actually displays the results of the sql (and it also writes them to the file).

However, if I run every single command from the sqlite console, everything works fine.  I only get the error when I run it from the SQLite console using .read

Any suggestions?  What am I missing?  I checked the docs in the SQLite website, and in the example presented they switch the output from console to file and back in the same manner.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.output` command expects a single parameter, not five.

This forms works fine:

```
.output stdout
```

Answer (score 5):

I think I found the problem:

```
.output stdout          --send output to screen
```

Apparently, the `--send...` was interpreted as an argument.  Removing the `--` and the comments after `stdout` fixed the problem.

Thanks!